# SWIFT Firestore fetch data with a query to filter whereField is equalTo a autoID failed

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to fetch posts under a biz by fetch posts with the same bizId field.
I have stored all Posts data under collection(posts)-> document(autoId) -> ...one of the field is "bId": bizId //the bizId of the biz data.

And I have stored alll Biz data under collection(bizs) -> document(autoId)

Say I am at Biz ViewController and I want to fetch all posts under this Biz in a collectionViewCell. I want to use (whereField("bId", isEqualTo: bizId) to fetch the posts associated with this biz from the posts pool. I receive error. I am only getting data output by following:

```
static func fetchPostFromBiz(forBiz: String, completion: @escaping ([Post]) -> Void) {
    let query = POST_REF.order(by: "ts", descending: true) // where ts is timestamp, if I add limit(to: 16) or whereField("bId", isEqualTo: forBiz) It fails to fetch
    query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if let err = error {
            print("error getting doc \(err)")
        } else {
            guard let docs = snapshot?.documents else {
                print("no doc exist showing empty cell")
                return}
            let posts = docs.map({Post(dateId: $0.documentID, dictionary: $0.data()) })
            completion(posts)
        }
    }
    
}
```

When I apply (whereField("bId", isEqualTo: bizId),I receive [] no dataOutput.
when I apply (whereF...Id).order(by:...).limit(to:..), I receive index needed error.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have this query:

> ```
> let query = POST_REF.order(by: "ts", descending: true) // where ts is timestamp, if I add limit(to: 16) or whereField("bId", isEqualTo: forBiz) It fails to fetch
> ```

When you try to make a combined use of more than one query operator or mix in collections you get Compound queries which according to [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing) this requires new indexes that have to be created by the user.

> Cloud Firestore ensures query performance by requiring an index for
> every query. The indexes required for the most basic queries are
> automatically created for you. As you use and test your app, Cloud
> Firestore generates error messages that help you create additional
> indexes your app requires.

As for this `(whereField("bId", isEqualTo: bizId)` not receiving data output, the syntax is technically correct the only reason it wouldn't return data is because there is either no data to be found using that value or bizId does not hold the value you are expecting, in which case I recommend you log data using the Analytics SDK, Using the Event Logger  you can visualize in a time graph when certain events are detected and filter these to find specific details or errors on your app, [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=ios) is more data regarding logging,

A single field query like `citiesRef.whereField("state", isEqualTo: "CA")` should have no issues with the index but you can also create an index for this.